# Global Variable Reference inside a function

Tags: python

I'm trying to reference a global variable inside a function. This function is being defined in a separate file and imported into the main file and applied to a dataset. Here's code:

```
def to_nominal(dataset):
    global ngdp
    global gdp_deflator_series
    
    bools = []
    for date in ngdp.Date:
        if date in set(dataset.Date).intersection(set(ngdp.Date)):
            bools.append(True)
        else: bools.append(False)
    
    npci_deflator_series = gdp_deflator_series[bools].reset_index(drop = True)
    
    bools = []
    for date in dataset.Date:
        if date in set(dataset.Date).intersection(set(ngdp.Date)):
            bools.append(True)
        else: bools.append(False)
        
    dataset_bools = dataset[bools]
    dataset = dataset_bools.reset_index(drop = True).drop(['YEAR', 'QUARTER', 'Date'], axis = 1).mul(npci_deflator_series, axis =0)
    dataset['Date'] = dataset_bools.Date
    return dataset
```

I throws the error: 'ngdp' not defined. Initially I though this was because I had to specify that ngdp was a global variable, but the problem seems to persist. I think it might have to do with the fact that i'm importing the function into another file? Any thoughts will be appreciated.

Comment: Where did you define or assign a value to the global variable?

Comment: Did I misunderstand this quesion? Which module has `ngdp`? As an aside, a smaller example demonstrating the problem makes it easier to answer. Also, post the full traceback so we can see details of the error.

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Your post fails to run on its own.  It shows no definition for `ngdp`.  We don't really have any definitive way to diagnose your problem.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it sounds like this function is being defined in module `A`, and imported into another module, `B`, that has `ngdp` in it's own globals, and you want `A.to_nominal` to make use of `B.ngdp`.

That's not possible. Global scope is tied to the module where the function is defined; even when you import the function into another module, it still looks for globals in the original module's (`A`) scope.

You need to either define both the global and the function in the same module (the simplest approach), or tie them together in some other way (ideally *not* via a circular import, with `A` importing `ngdp`, while `B` imports `to_nominal`, because that's error-prone as all get out). If they can't be in the same module, simply passing `ngdp` as an argument to `to_nominal` would be a reasonable solution.

Comment: You understood it exactly right. Thank you for the insight!